# check 2 array if values exist in the 2 array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var arr1= [];
var value = "value";

if ($.inArray(value, arr1) !== -1){
    //value found
}
```

To check for a value if it exist in array we use above code. What i need is to check a value from an array if it exist in another array. What i did is below. But i am not certain why i always get not found even if in the array there is a same value. Any suggestion is appreciated

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/62Lvw3r3/1/)

```
var arr1 = [{
    "id": "1"
}, {
    "id": "2"
}]
var arr2 = [{
    "id": "2"
}, {
    "id": "3"
}]
$.each(arr2, function (index, value) {
    console.log(value.id);
    if ($.inArray(value.id, arr1) !== -1) {
        alert('found');
    } else {
        alert('q');
    }
});
```

Comment: @arun i dont think it is a duplicate of the question you posted... My problem is i need to get every value from an array and check each value if it exist in another array. please clarify

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/szb5gwf9/1/

$.inArray only works with arrays

Comment: @eaCe thanks for that one but my array is dynamic and the way you check your array is like the example i posted above for checking array value from one array only..i need to check the value from 1 array if it exist in another array.. i hope i am not confusing anyone

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ybjvyt7r/1/ - I marked it as a duplicate because the logic needed is the same

Comment: i see i wasnt able to understand what exactly the question you posted is about that is why i said it is not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your inner comparison compares the id value ("2", "3") with the objects inside arr1 (which are NOT the values "1" & "2").

Even if you did compare objects (`value` instead of `value.id`), it won't work. That's because of the defined equality (or rather lack of...) of objects.

When comparing objects in JavaScript, the comparison is reference based, not value based. Consider this:

```js
alert({a:1} == {a:1})
```

The reason you don't see this problem with your first example is that string equality *is* value based.

In order to overcome this, you need to compare the values, or key-value pairs in your objects.

Comment: please give me time to understand the answer thank you

Comment: @BrownmanRevival - By all means, take your time.

Comment: now i understand what you are trying to say is i am comparing `2 == "id": "1"` and `3 == "id": "2"` since i am comparing the value of 2 with regards to the element(and not the value which are 1 and 2 respectively) in the arr1.. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the first part of my answer and the "direct" reason your code isn't working.